# how to create nodes and edges for sorghum gene list using gene id from Phytozome

Tags: cytoscape, rna-seq

I am using Sorghum ID from Phytozome in my RNAseq. I want to create gene network by cytoscape for specific gene list. Unfortunately, I could not use string or other tools because the gene id I used from Phytozome 12 is not recognized. So my question is how to overcome this problem and create nodes and edges for my gene list??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which ID you are using.  Phytozome transcript names (e.g. Sobic.008G038200.1)  don't work, but I was able to get the "Sb" symbols to work just fine in String. You could also try to map to the gene symbol (e.g. ACR4 for Sb08g003290).  Beyond that, you'll just have to do the mapping between the transcript names and a more common identifier (e.g. Ensembl or Entrez).

-- scooter